# Finding all solutions in linear programming

Tags: mathematical-optimization

It seems that the function `LinearProgramming` doesn't provide the option to find all solutions to a linear programming problem. Of course, if there are more than one then there are infinitely many solutions; what I need is the set of all *corner* solutions. Is there a convenient way to find all solutions in linear programming without implementing our own simplex algorithm? I'm thinking about combining finding the optimal value of the objective function (using `LinearProgramming`) with "reformulating" it with `Solve` (to find all solutions that satisfy reaching the now-known optimal value for the objective function)...

I'm using linear programming to find optimal strategies for players in a zero-sum two-player game (where the Minimax Theorem says that minimax = Nash equilibrium). The reason why I need all solutions is that the one instance found by `LinearProgramming` might not be a sequential equilibrium (I'm trying to solve extensive-form games by converting them to normal form).

Comment: Couldn't you just perturb the objective a little bit to get each corner solution? If you found all active constraints, and you add epsilon*constraint vector (for some small constant epsilon), you should get all corners, right?

Comment: could you please provide a small example of an extensive form game you are tackling that can be successfully solved with your proposed strategy?